# Rotate a Translation and a Quaternion around the z axis of an arbitrary pose by an angle theta

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, rotations, quaternions, rigid-transformation

I need to implement a rotation in a program but it's 15 years I haven't used rigid body motion maths.

I use poses that are described by a translation T and quaternion Q.

Everything is expressed in the world's coordinates.

I have a pose T1,Q1 that I need to move from an angle $\theta$ around the z axis of another pose Tr,Qr.

The problem look like that:

[image: Rotation around an axis. C0]

I need to find a transformation that goes from the frame T1,Q1 to the frame T2,Q2.

I found some explanations on how to apply a rotation but I'm still scratching my head on how to compound the transformations there.

If you could explain to me the general process there it will help me to clear my mind.

Thanks